# Give more space to my root partition

Tags: gparted, root

First of all, I know that this question has already been answer, but I need a little help. My "problem" is that I need to give more space to my root partition. This is my GParted screenshot:

[image: My GParted screenshot]

Comment: It's not clear exactly what help you need - are you looking for  what size these partitions need to be?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to extend the space of the root partition

Comment: `First of all, I know that this question has already been answer` ... so what are you asking, why is your problem different. I cannot see from the Question.

Comment: Because I thought someone could help me. I'm still learning about Linux and I don't want to crash anything.

Comment: Moving partitions left is not a great idea. It will take a long time and possibly put excessive wear on an older disk. Do you need 12 GB swap? The easiest thing is to boot from live medium, use gparted to delete the swap, expand /, saving 2 GB for swap, and then remake swap. You'll need to change the uuid of swap in /etc/fstab. You could also reinstall, using either the auto layout or Something Else option to get the setup that you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The procedures are detailed in the link that I gave as a reason to close this question - but to paraphrase them:

1. Make a backup of your data onto an external device (a usb drive?)
2. You need to create some empty space on your disk.  To do this you will need to shrink the '/dev/sda4' partition, by an amount equal to the space that you want to add to your root partition.
3. The extra space (from '/dev/sda4') will need to be congruent to (next to) '/dev/sda1', and to do this, you will need to move the remaining partitions ('/dev/sda2' and '/dev/sda3')
4. The final step will be to expand '/dev/sda1' into the open space.

Although you *can* move and resize '/dev/sda3' and '/dev/sda4' while you are using your computer, you probably cannot do the same for '/dev/sda1' and '/dev/sda2'.  To accomplish the whole resizing scheme, you should create a liveUSB and run `gparted` from that device to do the repartitioning.  It bears repeating at this point, that making a backup of your data before you do this is a really good idea.

Comment: Probably good to use a [gparted live usb](https://gparted.org/liveusb.php)

Comment: This is a very good idea. The only problem is that I don't have an external hard drive. Is there anything else that I can do?

Comment: I've read many articles about people being upset that they have lost data for many reasons.  Errors in using their programs and OSs, failures of hard disks, malicious software...  The point here is that if you have data which is important to you, or irreplaceable, then you should provide yourself with a way to back it up.

Comment: Agree. Thanks a lot for the help and patience Charles Green